# HTTP/2 with .Net Core and Kestrel

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to setup a Web Server with `Kestrel` in `ASP.Net Core 3.1` to support `HTTP/2`. So this is how I configure Kestrel:

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenLocalhost(8080, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    });
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
        }
}
```

And this is how I test it by making a request with prior `HTTP/2` knowledge in a console application:

```
class Program
{
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

            using var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080"),
                DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0)
            };
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");
            var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
            var version = res.Version;
            Console.WriteLine(version);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the caller program fails with this exception `IOException: The response ended prematurely`:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__53.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithRetryAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__70.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ConsoleApp17.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Hans\source\repos\ConsoleApp17\ConsoleApp17\Program.cs:line 19

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(bool)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]

Inner Exception 1:
IOException: The response ended prematurely.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have a ReadKey in the client but not in the server.  The server is terminating and disposing the connection.

Comment: @jdweng What???! The `Kestrel` server is inside an `ASP.NET Core` application.

Comment: Change the port to 5001

Comment: Is there anything running on http://localhost:8080? Does this answer help you?

Comment: @Hans : What stops the server code from terminating?  When the application closes so does the connection.

Comment: @MichaelMao No luck!

Comment: @Akif Nothing but my app. I changed the port to 5001 and still the same result

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is an issue - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27536#issuecomment-731932924
I tried with Http1 worked ok

```
listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
```

Comment: It's not a `grpc` call. It's a simple HTTP request

Comment: by default http2 is goes with encrypted messages but there is a way to disable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#http2-support